# Visual Studio 2013 automatically checking out .csproj

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

It all started since some update which I cannot recall exactly when happened. But since then, all my .csproj files for WebServices and ASP .Net projects are being automatically checked out  with the following changes:

`<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
<IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />`

To

`<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
 <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
 <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>false</IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>`

Even if the Undo operation is performed on the files, they keep getting checked out again with the same modifications.

Any hints on how to disable this behaviour?

Comment: is that a problem? why don't you just submit it?

Comment: well, as it may not be a problem that is blocking any of my progress it just seems wrong to me that i have to either submit the code that i have not changed or just keep having the files checked out forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio automatically applies settings for each web project based on the "applicationhost.config" file located on "My documents\IISExpress\config\".

Deleting the part related to my projects (there is a tag for each project in the file) did the work.

Source: http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2013/05/08/IIS-Express-Default-Settings.aspx

Comment: Just to inform that this solution doesn't seem to apply on VS2017, I'm having the same issue and those settings don't show up on "My documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config".